# How Can I Silence this PowerShell Error?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have an If statement in my script checking if an AD Object already exists. However, none of these evaluations prevent the host from printing the undesired evaluation "Directory object not found."

```
!$(Get-ADObject -Identity $ImportedObject.DistinguishedName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)


[void](!$(Get-ADObject -Identity $ImportedObject.DistinguishedName))


!$($(Get-ADObject -Identity $ImportedObject.DistinguishedName) | Out-Null)


$ErrorAction = $CurrentErrorAction
$ErrorAction = "SilentlyContinue"
!$(Get-ADObject -Identity $ImportedObject.DistinguishedName)
$ErrorAction = $CurrentErrorAction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `try{} ... catch{}` block like this

```
try 
{
// your code to find AD group goes here
}
  catch  {
      //whatever you want to do further
     }
```

Another way of doing this would be using the `-Filter` option of `Get-ADUser` commandlet

See [Get-ADUser Commandlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx)

Comment: I could not form a Filter statement that didn't result in a `path not found` or similar error. However, Try Catch worked well, and of course I should have done that to begin with. Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, to better form my script, I actually put the action in the try block and discarded any advance checking to see if it already exists. Then in the catch block I now intercept cases where it exists, and other errors as well.

Comment: @Tohuw, good to hear that it worked and yes try catch really helpful like it is in c# for runtime exception handling.